# why is my pokemon go plus not buzzing?

Tags: pokemon-go

My pokemon go plus do not seem to be working as it should.

I have paired it with the app, and the app confirms that there is a successful connection.

However, the go plus does not buzz when there is a pokestop or a pokemon around.

I wonder what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The latest update caused some issues with the PG+ not working. I was having issues as well but it seems the issues have been fixed. Restart the app/sever the connection between the PG+ and your phone and reconnect and see if that works.

If it's still not working within the next few hours/day then I'd start looking into other solutions.

Comment: it seems to be unstable is the main concern. Sometimes it works. And then sometimes it will just not work. And sometimes its not working even when the app says its connected. Very erratic. Sometimes turning on the screen seems to make it react again. But why.